# Kibana 4 Map View with ISO CountryCodes

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I have a issue with plotting my data set on Iso Country code. The only option available seems to be Geo Coordinates. Is their option for Iso country code or not? I have been looking around on the net for a while and can’t find any good thread or any solution on this problem. If it´s not possible, is there any workaround on this problem?